# Page not found at /

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and according to tutorial i've created the project:

[image: project directory structure]

views.py code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is the home page")


def about(request):
    data = "This is our about page"
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

urls.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home),
    path('about/', views.about),
]
```

Error i get while running the app:

[image: web error]

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want drf to recognize empty path, you shall set something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.some_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home),
    path('about/', views.about),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not set any view for this url `/` go on `home/` or `about/` url than you will see your message or you can change `home/` url empty like this `path('', views.home),` to access your home view to main domain.